# Is there an exact solution to the product $\prod _{n=1}^{\infty} \left(2-e^\frac{1}{\left(p_n\right){}^s}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I have been able to simplify the product to:
$$ \prod _{n=1}^{\infty} \left(2-e^\frac{1}{\left(p_n\right){}^s}\right) = \exp \left(-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{Li}_{1-n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) P(n s)}{n!}\right)$$
where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime, $Li_s(x)$ is the Polylogarithm, and $P(s)$ is the Prime Zeta Function.
To make sure I hadn't made a mistake the following table gives some values.

\begin{array}{ccc}
 s &  LHS & RHS \\
 3 & 0.823535399 & 0.823535399 \\
 4 & 0.921900096 & 0.921900096 \\
 5 & 0.963887897 & 0.963887897 \\
 6 & 0.982829133 & 0.982829133 \\
\end{array}

The left-hand-side seems so simple so I figured there should *at least* be a function that makes it pseudo-closed form.

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form or even a pseudo-closed form. But I might be wrong. By the way, what motivates you for this question?

Comment: I was experimenting with q-products and related products and was curious if there were prime analogues that weren't simple Euler products. A quick arbitrary example (the left hand side) gave me the right hand side after some rearranging. It appears that neither forms have sparked any recognition thus far.